# How can you separate Traits' source files and keep them type-checked in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

The example below will type-check and compile correctly in Groovy 2.5.
I would like to define the traits in two separate source files for clarity. This split leads to a undefined static type for the property access B.a in x().

Question: Is there a way to configure or hint the type check so it considers the definition of the trait?

It seems that this property is quite desirable, given that multiple inheritance is tricky and a type-check is especially valuable under these
circumstances.

```
package traits.example                                                                                                    

import groovy.transform.CompileStatic                                                                                                              

@CompileStatic                                                                                                                                     

trait A {                                                                                                                                          
    String a                                                                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                                                  

trait B implements A {                                                                                                                             

    def x() {                                                                                                                                      
        a                                                                                                                                          
    }                                                                                                                                              
}
```

Comment: Could you produce [mcve] for this problem? Extracting traits to a separate files (file per trait) works correctly, both from compiler (`groovyc`) or IDE (like IntelliJ IDEA). Trait compiles to Java's interface and the same conventions like packaging, files structure etc. applies to Groovy's traits.

Comment: Simply moving the current example into 2 files works for me as well, though there is some crazy whitespace in the code (which I cleaned up on my computer).